# Proving: 2 Möbius transformations are equal iff their associated matrices are equal

Tags: complex-analysis

I need some help proving the following:

> 2 Möbius transformations are equal if and only if their associated matrices are equal. (except of a multiplicative constant)

#### Proving $\boldsymbol\Leftarrow$

Let $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ have the associated matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$.

Let $g$ have the associated matrix $\begin{pmatrix}ma & mb\\ mc & md\end{pmatrix}$

Then it's nearly trivial.

#### Proving $\boldsymbol\Rightarrow$

Here I get kinda stuck in all of the unknown variables... I guess there must be a short way.

I tried:

Let

$$f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}\qquad g(z) = \frac{kz+l}{pz+q}$$

Then the difference yields

$$(az+b)(pz+q) - (kz+l)(cz+d) = 0$$

Expanding this further gets quite messy...

But I don't see how I could derive $k= m\cdot a, l = m\cdot b$ etc... (for a certain constant $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Think about the values of $z$ which go to $0,1,\infty$. For example, suppose $f(z_0)=g(z_0)=0$ What can you say about $-\frac ba$ and $-\frac lk$?

Comment: Hi, I found your answer. I am trying to solve this exercise but I still don't see the point. I know that $-\frac{a}{b}=-\frac{l}{k}$ but I still don't see how I can derive the asserption. Can you help me?